# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to execute JUnit 4 test in Intellij 2018.2.RC

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlintest

When trying to execute a very simple Hello World test in Android, using KotlinTest:

```
class ExampleUnitTest : FreeSpec() {

init {
    "Test" {
        2 + 2 shouldBe 4
    }
   }
}
```

When trying to execute this in IntelliJ, by clicking the green icon, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:45)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using this dependency:

```
testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit4:3.1.8"
```

JUnit 4 is necessary because Android doesn't support JUnit 5 yet.

**When executing `./gradlew test` it works correctly**, so I assume this is a problem with IntelliJ only?

Comment: IDEA CE 2019.2, issue is still here. Big thanks for 3.1.5 workaround. Did you submit bugreport to JetBrains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of what is causing this, but after hours of useless research, 
I've found a workaround to solve this issue.

It seems to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.RC, that causes it to execute code using JUnit 5 anyways. It looks like that it does that because it doesn't find any other TestExecutor in the classpath.

A Workaround to this is forcing your UnitTest to be compiled after IntelliJ builds it.

---

For that, edit your tests configuration:

[image]

And add a Gradle task to `compileDebugUnitTestKotlin`:

[image]

After this, your tests should become green again.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue which got resolved when I clicked on the "reload all projects" option

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and adding `app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin` to run configuration didn't work for me. I even replaced `Gradle-aware Make` with `Build` to get the same configuration, but it didn't help either.

I also tried to annotate the class with `@RunWith(JUnit4::class)` since you suggested it was executed with Junit 5. But this also didn't help.

What helped though was to downgrade to `3.1.5`. But it's not the best solution, since there are some useful functions in newer versions.

It's good to know it works from command line though. This way I can use the newest version and run tests using the Gradle run configuration for `app:test` and look at results in the browser. Not perfect, but...

Comment: I did find a workaround by downgrading to 3.1.5, And [this was reported to the developer](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/385)

Comment: But it's very unfortunate that executing compileDebugunitTestKotlin didn't work for you :x

Comment: You can also execute in Terminal -> `./gradlew test` and see the test results it generates (it's an index.html file) in the browser